# Using SSIS to build a database from a VS2005/2008 database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, ssis

How do I allow an SSIS package to consume a Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 Database project which houses the creation scripts for the tables and other objects (note: this is not Visual Studio Database Edition - just Pro with Business Intelligence)?

The idea is to use this to recreate my test instance by building the schema from source safe and the data from prod.

I have access to both VS2005 and 2008 Pro and this is hitting Sql Server 2005 for both Prod and Test.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you cannot "allow an ssis package to consume a VS 2005 or 2008 db project". I am not sure why you want to use SSIS to run the create scripts. You can run the scripts from sqlcmd utility.

If you still want to use SSIS, this is what I would do:

- create a deployment script (VS for DB Pro can do that)
- create a package
- in your control flow, use Execute Process Task and configure it to run sqlcmd with the script file as your input

Answer (score 0):

You can call the scripts in the DB project through Execute SQL tasks in the SSIS package. However, there's not a direct way to consume them.